# "Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503" at NGINX Insgress Controller pod in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, readinessprobe

I wanted to expose a web application using NGINX Ingress Controller.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.29.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.29.2
```

NGINX Ingress controller version is 3.4.3

I searched that these versions are supposed to be compatible.

I followed the ingress controller installation on https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installing-nic/installation-with-manifests/ , choosing to install through manifests (since I am more used to them) and NodePort type of service.

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployments/common/ns-and-sa.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f deployments/rbac/rbac.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f deployments/common/nginx-config.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f deployments/common/ingress-class.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f deployments/deployment/nginx-ingress.yaml
$ kubectl create -f deployments/service/nodeport.yaml
```

After checking `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` I noticed the following on the nginx-ingress pod:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress          pod/nginx-ingress-755bf8968b-tmdps               0/1     Running   0          76m
```

Afterwards I ran `kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-755bf8968b-tmdps -n nginx-ingress` which showed:

```
Warning  Unhealthy  4m21s (x4549 over 79m)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

I also check the labels app=nginx-ingress on the pod and it's correct.

Outpuf of `kubectl logs -l app=nginx-ingress -n nginx-ingress`:

```
W0326 16:09:12.078133       1 reflector.go:539] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: failed to list *v1.VirtualServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualservers.k8s.nginx.org)
E0326 16:09:12.078276       1 reflector.go:147] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: Failed to watch *v1.VirtualServer: failed to list *v1.VirtualServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualservers.k8s.nginx.org)
W0326 16:09:32.474319       1 reflector.go:539] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: failed to list *v1.VirtualServerRoute: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualserverroutes.k8s.nginx.org)
E0326 16:09:32.474345       1 reflector.go:147] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: Failed to watch *v1.VirtualServerRoute: failed to list *v1.VirtualServerRoute: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualserverroutes.k8s.nginx.org)
W0326 16:09:39.265682       1 reflector.go:539] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: failed to list *v1.TransportServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get transportservers.k8s.nginx.org)
E0326 16:09:39.265849       1 reflector.go:147] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: Failed to watch *v1.TransportServer: failed to list *v1.TransportServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get transportservers.k8s.nginx.org)
W0326 16:09:48.080045       1 reflector.go:539] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: failed to list *v1.Policy: the server could not find the requested resource (get policies.k8s.nginx.org)
E0326 16:09:48.080101       1 reflector.go:147] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: Failed to watch *v1.Policy: failed to list *v1.Policy: the server could not find the requested resource (get policies.k8s.nginx.org)
W0326 16:09:57.631094       1 reflector.go:539] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: failed to list *v1.VirtualServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualservers.k8s.nginx.org)
E0326 16:09:57.631121       1 reflector.go:147] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.29.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: Failed to watch *v1.VirtualServer: failed to list *v1.VirtualServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualservers.k8s.nginx.org)
```

What can I do? Following tutorials and documentation there shouldn't be any complications with the installation.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73968863/nginx-ingress-failed-http-probe-failed-with-statuscode-503

Comment: It is related, maybe even the same problem... The answers still do not help solve the problem: the first only suggests installing the ingress through helm, another asks for more output and the discussion is about the versions, which I made sure to check are compatible though the official documentation.

Comment: You can try do remove the Readiness probe from the nginx ingress yaml and check if that fix the issue....I the issue gets fixed, then the yaml wasnt perfect and needs some works like adding initial delay to the readiness probe....I mean, you are following the official docs and it's still failing right? Then maybe it's the files that had some issues...maybe the guys that mantains the manifests are a biy laizy or all the effort is on the helm side.

Comment: Removing the probe solved it. The pod is running and "Ready 1/1". 
Thank you @Hackerman for reading my post. 
Actually today version 3.5.0 of the ingress came out and they actually updated the documentation on the manifests... I wonder why this is even a problem for me and other people.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by commenting the following lines on the deployment yaml:

```
#readinessProbe:
#  httpGet:
#    path: /nginx-ready
#    port: readiness-port
#  periodSeconds: 1
```

I still wonder why is this an issue that occured to me and also other people such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73968863/nginx-ingress-failed-http-probe-failed-with-statuscode-503) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602906/kubernetes-pods-probe-failed-client-timeout-exceeded-while-awaiting-headers?rq=2)

The logs of the pod still registers the same as before (messages of server not finding certain resources).